# Laravel no message error in Form::open

Tags: php, laravel-5

Hi I am using Laravel version 5.6 and got No message in a view using a Form::open with the code below

`{!! Form::open(['route' => array('admin.msgs.send', 'id'=>$user->id)]) !!}`

But I got the route on registred on my file, just like this:

`Route::get('msgs/send/{id}', ['as'=>'admin.msgs.send', 'uses'=>'MsgsController@send']);`

Some one knows what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`{!! Form::open(['route' => ['route.name', $user->id]]) !!}`

or:

`{!! Form::open(['route' => ['route.name', ['id' => $user->id]]]) !!}`

Comment: the 1° gives me the same thing, No message Exception. But the 2° gives an ErrorException Array to string conversion in the view, it doens't even let me execute the form

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the type of the method, I realized the route was registred as GET and not as POST, which is the type of a form.